# IntelliJ Warns of Possible NPE in Unit Test, Right After Notnull Assertion

Tags: intellij-idea, nullpointerexception

This code is leaving a warning in the editor:

```
assertThat(dateTextView.getText(), notNullValue());
assertThat(dateTextView.getText().toString(), is("01:00 PM"));
```

Seems insane to wrap every assertion of some text value in a null check when you are already asserting that it's not null. I like the NPE warnings, but not here.

The warning is:

```
Warning: method invocation dateTextView.getText() may produce java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Looking for a better solution.

Comment: where is the warning? Specifically, what is underlined in the warning?

Comment: Please broaden the context a bit. We would like to see where the `dateTextView` variable is coming from

Comment: What? it's a TextView component in Android. The point is, their lint tool is smart enough to tell if you are checking with an if, but not smart enough to see you are asserting that it's not null. In their defense, I am using a different assertion mechanism: hamcrest.

Comment: In plugin development, even if you were using an `if`, the warning could show up if the result of `getText()` may change over time. Then you'd have to assign the result to a variable before using it.